# Alternative way of coding Content in Font Awesome CSS

Tags: css, font-awesome

Wordpress is stripping out the slash from

```
  content:"\f12b";
```

in my CSS to display a Font Awesome icon.  I can only use CSS in this particular case.  Can anyone suggest a workaround/alternative way of stipulating the content number?

Thank you!!

Comment: That's strange. Can you share the link with this issue?

Comment: Did you use `font-family: "FontAwesome"` ?

Comment: No - sorry -  it looks so bad I can't leave it live.  Apparently it's a security thing -  when I place the code in the theme customisation custom.css.  And sadly I need to have the code there.

Comment: Yes @odedta I use font-family: 'FontAwesome';

Comment: Wordpress shouldn't do anything like you describe really... did you try to disable all your plugins?

Comment: Use `font-family: "FontAwesome"; content:"&#xf12b;";`

Comment: @ odedta Apparently Wordpress does that when the code is in Appearance>Customise>Custom Css.  It happens when all plugins are disabled.  Also happens on my test site.  @ Germano Plebani  Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it but unfortunately it displayed &#xf12b; instead of the icon.